# Restore ALL information after factory reset

Tags: backup

I've done a factory reset on my Samsung galaxy A5 (2016) with android 6.0.1.

I've done a factory reset today,  then restored my account from Google drive.  Many things have been restored correctly,  although some are not restored,  like:

- themes and background picture
- organisation of apps on home screen
- memos
- alarms in clock app
- cookies in chrome
- ...

Is there a way to get them back?
If not, then is there a way (app) to backup them?

### Update

I'd to restore my phone as its gps wasn't working (I've tried various apps to fix / reset it without success)

Notes: I mean built-in notes app of my phone.

Theme & backound: no those haven't been restored

Comment: A [Nandroid](https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/NANDroid) backup would restore *everything*. Some apps just don't allow to be backed up (correctly) or refuse to restore. Therefore a Nandroid backup is the only full backup solution.

Comment: No offense... but what is the point of doing a factory reset if you are just going to go back to exactly the same thing? Many of the things you are asking about are application dependent... Themes I know nothing about, background picture SHOULD restore from Google (mine always does), organization of apps on home screen is dependent on the Launcher (some have a backup/restore function), "Memos" are app dependent, if you used Google Keep they would have been restored, Alarms are dependent on the clock app supporting Google backup, etc... Problem is restoring now is impossible, the info is gone.

Comment: @acejavelin: please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restore using the Samsung Cloud. I've done this recently and I got back my sms messages, alarms,  background,  and everything. Hopefully your backup was setup automatically on your phone...This quick youtube video might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ly8HyxbXQGU

Comment: Thanks. I thought Samsung backup and Google account backup are doing the same,  so disabled Samsung,  I've switched it on.